# TemplateSyntaxError at \stats2

Tags: python, django

this is my django code

```
def stats2_view(request):
    monthly_expenses={}
    months_ = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    # if request.method == 'POST':
    #     year = request.POST.get('selected_year')
        # if year:
    expenses = Expense.objects.filter(owner=request.user, date__year=2024)
    monthly_expenses = calculate_expense_month_summary(expenses) 
    years = range(2010, datetime.datetime.now().year+1)
    return render(request, 'expense/stats2.html', {'expense_month_data': monthly_expenses,'yr': years,'months':months_})
```

and,
this template

```
<div class="col-md-6">
          <h2>Details</h2>
          <div class="text-md-start center-paragraph">
            <h3>For the year 2024 the break down for each month is as follows</h3>
            {% for month_num, expense in expense_month_data.items %}
              <p>Total amount spent in {{ months[month_num]}} till now is <span class="fw-bold">{{ expense }}</span></p>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
      </div>
```

error Im receiving
TemplateSyntaxError at /stats2

i want to print month from the index

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `bracket notation` to access dictionary values in Django Template Language. Use a `dot notation` instead.

```html
... 
{% for month_num, expense in expense_month_data.items %}
    <p>Total amount spent in {{ months.month_num }} till now is <span class="fw-bold">{{ expense }}</span></p>
{% endfor %}
...
```

Comment: This will not work, since it is not the `month_num` as key, but the *value* of a variable named `month_num`.

Comment: I assumed `months` was a dictionary.

Comment: it is, but `months.month_num` will perform a lookup `months['month_num']`, so regardless if there is a variable named `month_num`, and what its value is, it will not use that.

Answer (score 0):

Django's template language does *not* support subscripting (i.e. `x[y]`), this has been done deliberately to prevent people from writing *business logic* in the templates. One can use [*Jinja*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/) as a template language, but this is not necessary and to some extent counterproductive, precisely to prevent writing business logic in the template.

```
def stats2_view(request):
    months_ = [
        'January',
        'February',
        'March',
        'April',
        'May',
        'June',
        'July',
        'August',
        'September',
        'October',
        'November',
        'December',
    ]
    expenses = Expense.objects.filter(owner=request.user, date__year=2024)
    monthly_expenses = calculate_expense_month_summary(expenses)
    monthly_expenses = {months_[k]: v for k, v in monthly_expenses.items()}
    return render(
        request, 'expense/stats2.html', {'expense_month_data': monthly_expenses}
    )
```

and render with:

```
{% for month, expense in expense_month_data.items %}
    <p>Total amount spent in {{ month }} till now is <span class="fw-bold">{{ expense }}</span></p>
{% endfor %}
```